# css combine id and class

Tags: css, class, syntax

```
div id="projectpage">
        <?
        foreach($projects as $project) {

            ?>
            <div class="project">
                <h2><?=$project->date;?></h2>

                <h1><a href="project.php?id=<?=$project->id;?>"><?=$project->title;?></a></h1>
                    <div class="primary-image">
                        <a href="project.php?id=<?=$project->id;?>"><img src="media/<?=$project->primary_image->filename;?>"></a>
                    </div>

                <div id="tag">
                    <h2 id="tag"><?=$project->tag1;?></h2>
                </div>


                <h1 id="caption"><?=$project->caption;?></h1>



            </div>
            <?
        }

        ?>
    </div>
```

and this is the css

```
.project {
    width: 30%;
    margin: 18px;
    position: relative;
    display: inline-block;
    background-color: pink;
}

.project h1{
    text-align: center;
    font-family: "Futura";
    font-size: 50px;
}

.project h1 a {
    color: #000;
    text-decoration: none;
}

.project h1 a:hover {
    color: #000;
    border-bottom: 2px solid #000;
}

.project h2{
    text-align: center;
    font-family: "Futura";
    font-size: 15px;
}

.project#caption h1{
    text-align: center;
    font-family: "Futura";
    font-size: 10px;
}
```

I want my h1 caption to correspond to the css which I have written for it, but I cant seen to get the syntax right in the CSS with the combination of an id and a class selector. The css of project. h1 seems to overrule the caption h1.

Answer (score 1):

You have no `.project` object with that id (which is what your CSS specifies).

```
.project#caption h1 {
```

should be

```
.project h1#caption {
```

Although this won't work that well, since you have multiple `h1` elements with that same `id`. `id` must be unique through the document; you probably want a `caption` class instead, which you'd address as

```
.project .caption
```

Answer (score 0):

Since the id is unique you can use this css selector:

```
h1#caption{
    /* your css */
}
```

To combine a class and an id the id should be in front of the class (but you don't need to in this case, use the code above):

```
#caption.project h1{
    /* your css */
}
```

Comment: The `id` won't be unique; a series of `project` divs are being output within a PHP loop. All will have the same `caption` id, along with multiple `tag` ids, etc.

Comment: Then you should change it to a class :)

Comment: If I were the OP, I suppose I would. I suggested as much in my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Try changing the css for the caption to:

```
h1#caption {
    text-align: center;
    font-family: "Futura";
    font-size: 10px;
}
```

Using an "ID" css selector will ensure it always wins over css "class" selectors. Also, if you want, you can also get rid of the text-align and font-family in this class since it's already being applied in your `.project h1` css declaration.

Answer (score 0):

In your example you only need the ID. The ID is supposed to be unique in the entire page. In your example, just using `#caption` is enough.

I can see a use case for using classes with it though. If say you conditionally add/remove a class and want the presence of the class to have some UI effect.

So, this is how you do it:

```
#caption.project {

}
```

Which means change your example bit to:

```
#caption.project {
    text-align: center;
    font-family: "Futura";
    font-size: 10px;
}
```

You could also use `h1#caption.project` to add the tag to it, but I don't see a point in this, unless the CSS is really messy and you have to override other style or something without changing it. That's, again, a very messy situation to be in anyway.